# Differences in SPI SCK for half and full duplex mode

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, embedded

I am using SPI to communicate with the radio module; I want to use full duplex but I noticed a few things:

- when I set the `BIDIMODE` to 1 (1-line bidirectional), I see a clock running at 6KHz. I am using a prescalar of 2 and my system clock is 16MHz, so shouldn't it be generating 8MHz clock?

[image]

- when I use `BIDIMODE` to 0 (2-line unidirectional == full duplex),  I don't even see a single clock pulse. Interestingly, I receive `28` in the rx buffer but I don't see anything like that in the LA output. Why am I seeing this difference by changing the mode? Changing the mode afaik shouldn't change the clock's behavior, but rather in full duplex, you're receiving and sending simultaneously.

[image]

**MCU: STM32F401RE nucleo**

Following is my full duplex config for SPI:

```
SPI_InitTypeDef spi_config = {
        Mode: SPI_MODE_MASTER,
        Direction: SPI_DIRECTION_2LINES,            
        DataSize: SPI_DATASIZE_8BIT,
        CLKPolarity: SPI_POLARITY_LOW,
        CLKPhase: SPI_PHASE_1EDGE,
        NSS: SPI_NSS_SOFT,
        BaudRatePrescaler: SPI_BAUDRATEPRESCALER_2,
        FirstBit: SPI_FIRSTBIT_MSB,
        TIMode: SPI_TIMODE_DISABLE,
        CRCCalculation: SPI_CRCCALCULATION_DISABLE,
        CRCPolynomial: 7
};
SPI_Init(&spi_config, SPI2);
```

Comment: The clock only runs when you transmit.  You don't show any code that writes to SPI data register.

If you write to SPI data register, does the status register show the data being sent (so you should see a TX empty type of status)?

Is your radio module a master or slave?

Comment: What radio module?

Comment: @RobinIddon yes so when I use two line direction, I do see respective TxISR() &RxISR() being triggered. Radio is slave and MCU is master

Comment: @Andyaka nrf24l01

Comment: Then either you have not pinmuxed the pins or you are violating the max clock rate for the peripheral or your logic analyser.  Try using a much lower clock rate and see what happens.